# How do I dynamically generate a list of Widgets which can be toggled using a bool for each widget when the number of widgets is dynamic?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to parse a JSON With multiple categories of entries (organized into sections using an optional key called "section". The layout for this is as follows:

```
Map<String, dynamic> itemList = {
'Dry Clean': [
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D001', 'image': 'images/t-shirt.png', 'item': 'T-Shirt', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'section' : "Regular"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D002', 'image': 'images/jeans.png', 'item': 'Jeans', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'section' : "Regular"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D003', 'image': 'images/kurta.png', 'item': 'Kurta', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'starch': false, 'section' : "Ethnic"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D004', 'image': 'images/pyjama.png', 'item': 'Pyjama', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'section' : "Ethnic"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D005', 'image': 'images/lehenga.png', 'item': 'Lehenga', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'section' : "Ethnic"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D006', 'image': 'images/lehenga-heavy.png', 'item': 'Lehenga Heavy', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'section' : "Ethnic"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D007', 'image': 'images/jacket.png', 'item': 'Jacket', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'section' : "Regular"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D008', 'image': 'images/blouse.png', 'item': 'Blouse', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'section' : "Ethnic"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D009', 'image': 'images/dupatta.png', 'item': 'Dupatta', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'starch': false, 'section' : "Ethnic"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D010', 'image': 'images/leggings.png', 'item': 'Leggings', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'section' : "Regular"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D011', 'image': 'images/shirt.png', 'item': 'Shirt', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'starch': false, 'section' : "Regular"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D012', 'image': 'images/trousers.png', 'item': 'Trousers', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'section' : "Regular"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D013', 'image': 'images/dhoti.png', 'item': 'Silk Dhoti', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'starch': false, 'section' : "Ethnic"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D014', 'image': 'images/dhoti.png', 'item': 'Cotton Dhoti', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'section' : "Ethnic"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D015', 'image': 'images/saree.png', 'item': 'Cotton Saree', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'starch': false, 'section' : "Ethnic"},
  {'action': 'Dry Clean', 'id': 'D016', 'image': 'images/saree.png', 'item': 'Silk Saree', 'service': 'Dry Clean', 'stainRemoval': false, 'starch': false, 'section' : "Ethnic"}
],}
```

This is parsed by the following function :

```
Widget _populateItemsWithCategories(String category, Color color ) {
    List<String> sections = [];
    print("_populateItemsWithCategories : ${category}");

// handle special category items

if(category == 'special') {
  return GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: gridSize,
    mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
    childAspectRatio: 1,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 15, 5, 0),
    children: _populateItems(category, color),
  );
}

// if not special, then parse the json to see if you have sections


for (var item in itemList![category]) {
  if(item.containsKey('section')) {
    String section = item!['section'];
    sections.add(section);
  }
}
List<String> uniqueSections = sections.toSet().toList();
if(uniqueSections.isEmpty){

  //no sections, just return a GridView

return GridView.count(
crossAxisCount: gridSize,
mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
childAspectRatio: 1,
padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 15, 5, 0),
children: _populateItems(category, color),
);
} 
else {
// we have sections, parse the JSON and create a list of unique sections and associated bools to toggle visibility

  int sectionCount = uniqueSections.length;
  List<bool> sectionBools = [];
  List<Widget> widgetList = [];

  for(int i=0; i < sectionCount; i++) {
    sectionBools.add(true);
  }
  for(int i=0; i < sectionCount; i++){

    // now add a list with a leading GestureDetector to toggle the section followed by a GridView with the section

    List<Widget> thisSection = [
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: (() {
        setState(() {
          print("i is ${i}, category is ${category}, section is ${uniqueSections[i]}, bool value is ${sectionBools[i]}");
          sectionBools[i] = !sectionBools[i];
          print("i is ${i}, category is ${category}, section is ${uniqueSections[i]}, bool value is ${sectionBools[i]}");
        });
      }),

      child: Container(
        height: 25,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              uniqueSections[i],
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .bodyLarge,
            ),
            Container(width: 5,),
            sectionBools[i] ? Icon(Icons.remove_sharp) : Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
// here is where we have an issue. The code makes sure the GridView is never added at all, but we want to have a flag through which the visibility is toggled

        if(!sectionBools[i])  
          GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisCount: gridSize,
            mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
            childAspectRatio: 1,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 15, 5, 0),
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: _populateItems(category, color, section: uniqueSections[i]),
          ),
        ];
        widgetList.addAll( thisSection);
        print(widgetList);
      }

      return ListView(shrinkWrap: true, controller: _scrollController, padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15), children: widgetList);
     
  }
  }
```

I planned to have the sectionBools[i] work as a flag to toggle visibility of sections when the GestureDetector is triggered.

However what is happening is that because the sectionBools[i] variable is false by default, the list is rendered without the GridView in the list at all. CLicking on the title triggers the text but the ListView needs to be regenerated to show/enable the GridViews which is not happening.

How do I dynamically generate a list of Widgets which can be toggled using a bool for each widget (in this case, GridView)?